# Como deixar plugin de comentarios do facebook com largura de 100%?

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

Existe alguma possibilidade de deixar o plugin do facebook com largura de 100%?

Acho que padrão dele é largura de 550px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Actualização

Ao que parece o método do Facebook não está a aceitar percentagens através da opção de configuração `data-width`, dado o valor da mesma estar a ser convertido para pixeis independentemente do indicador do tipo de valor utilizado (%, pt, px).

Se nada for definido, existe um elemento dentro da `iframe`, especificamente uma `div#feedback_xxxxxx` que recebe a largura por defeito de 550 pixeis pelo que qualquer solução através do site via CSS fica inviabilizada.

#### Solução com jQuery

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/sZdWM/)

```js
$(function() {

    var $myWrap = $('body');                      // elemento wrapper dos comentários
        width   = $myWrap.width();                // recolhemos a largura em pixeis

    $('.fb-comments').attr("data-width", width);  // passamos a largura para o Facebook
});
```

#### Resultado:

[image: Captura de Tela do resultado]

## Redimensionar quando a tela muda de largura

Para que possamos redimensionar quando a tela muda de largura, e porque existem controlos de largura dentro da `iframe` cujo próprio *Comments PlugIn* utiliza, podemos escutar quando é que a janela deixou de ser redimensionada de forma a correr a função que vai definir a nova largura para os comentários do Facebook.

Assim sendo, criamos uma função que realiza as diversas operações e uma para escutar se a janela parou de ser redimensionada:

[**Demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/3LRe3/)

```
// função para manipular a largura do PlugIn de comentários do Facebook
function fluidComments() {
    var $myWrap = $('body');             // elemento wrapper dos comentários
        width   = $myWrap.width();       // recolhemos a largura em pixeis

    // passamos a largura para o Facebook
    $('.fb-comments').attr("data-width", width);

    /* se existe a iFrame é porque não é o primeiro carregamento
     * e também precisas de a actualizar
     */
    if ($(".fb-comments > span > iframe").size()==1)
        FB.XFBML.parse(); // indicação ao código do Facebook para se actualizar
}

// Correr quando o DOM está pronto
$(function() {
    fluidComments();
});

/* Monitorizar o progresso do "resize" para saber se acabou
 * e assim chamar a função que manipula a largura
 */    
var progresso;
window.onresize = function(){
  clearTimeout(progresso);
  progresso = setTimeout(fluidComments, 100);
};
```

---

## Resposta Original

Se por PlugIn de Comentários estás-te a referir ao [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, podes definir a largura do mesmo através de um atributo data:

> **data-width**
>
> The width (in pixels) of the plugin. The mobile version of the Comments plugin ignores the width parameter, and instead has a fluid width of 100%.

Que traduzido:

> **data-width**
>
> A largura (em pixels) do plugin. A versão para mobile do plug-in Comentários ignora o parâmetro de largura, e em vez disso tem uma largura fluída de 100%.

## Exemplo de implementação

```
 <div class="fb-comments"
      data-href="http://example.com/comments" 
      data-width="100%" 
      data-numposts="5" 
      data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Comment: Coloquei desse mesmo jeito, mas ele ficou com 100px e não 100%

Comment: Tem como colocar isso dentro de um resize() ?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison Tem sim, por favor lê a secção "Redimensionar quando a tela muda de largura" na minha resposta.

Comment: Isso mesmo @Zull, deu certo.. é normal de quando redimensionar o browser ficar como se tivesse carregando?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison É normal sim, efectivamente temos que dizer ao código do Facebook para actualizar o PlugIn, e isso a que te referes é o PlugIn a auto-actualizar-se. Quando o bug da largura estiver resolvido da parte deles, deixa de ser necessário este _workaround_.

Comment: Entendi @Zuul, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

Segundo essa [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7792873/195417), é possível sim:

Use o CSS:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style] {width: 100% !important;}
```

**EDIT:** Pelo jeito isso é um bug do facebook, introduzido recentemente... mas pelo que parece, existe uma forma de contornar o problema, como mostram as respostas no SOEN:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22328835/195417
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199776/195417

Comment: Ja tinha visto isso, não deu certo :(

Comment: Adicionei mais informações... depois vou transcrever as respostas do SOEN, em português, claro! =D

Answer (score 1):

Com [css](/questions/tagged/css) poderia usar as classes:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments span[style], .fb-comments iframe[style] {
width: 100% !important;
}
```